# Navigate to href when animation ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm trying to make a section fade out before following a link like so

```
<a class="fadelink" href="path/to/file">Hello</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $("a.fadelink").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();         
            $("#content").fadeTo(400,0,function(){
                window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Problem is, jQuery keeps returning me with "undefined" and 404's the redirect.

Comment: `this` is for `#content` not `a.fadelink` in your code.

Comment: are you trying to access the `href` attribute of `a.fadelink` or `#content` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `$(this)` in `$(this).attr("href")` is pointing to `$("#content")` which is **wrong**.  Move it into the right scope:

```
$("a.fadelink").on("click", function( evt ) {

   evt.preventDefault();   

   var goTo = $(this).attr("href");           // get href value of `this` anchor

   $("#content").fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
       window.location = goTo;                // Now you can use it
   });

});
```

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that before posting, maybe I need more caffeine. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @RichardDenton make one for me too!

Comment: Please stop wasting CPU cycles: `this.href` is less to type and very much faster (not that anyone will notice but you will feel happier having disturbed fewer electrons).

Comment: @RobG actually your comment "`this.href is less to type and very much faster`" is out of place cause `$(this).attr('href')` != `this.href` but rather `element.getAttribute('href')` that was my actual intention to add to the answer but I'm glad now we had the opportunity to discuss about it.

Comment: When is an A element's href attribute not identical to its href property? Since they are identical, there's no point in creating an additional jQuery object to call an additional jQuery function that (maybe) finally calls a host method versus simple property access.

Comment: @RobG http://jsbin.com/opakux/1/edit partially agreeing on your comment. Thanks for pointing that out, but in some occasions it's not an option to retrieve the full HREF.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong about them always being the same. The property returns the full URL regardless if the href attribute is a relative URL, the attribute returns the actual value (except in some browsers that return the full URL). Anyhow, the OP wants the property, not the attribute, so the correct jQuery method is `prop`, but it's still not required (and still way less efficient than direct property access).

Answer (score 2):

You're referring to the wrong `this`. The `href` attribute is present on the anchor, not the `#content` element.

```
$("a.fadelink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = this;
    $("#content").fadeTo(400,0,function(){
        window.location.href = $(that).attr("href");

    });
});
```